# which LaTeX .sty files are in each MacPorts texlive-* bundle?

Tags: packages, texlive

Is there a list of which particular LaTeX .sty files are installed for a given MacPorts texlive bundle?  For instance, which are in texlive-fonts-extra or texlive-science?

I know this list must exist somewhere.  I've been googling around for the past 20 minutes with no success.

I recently did an OS update and am reinstalling.  I used to have a TON of packages installed and probably don't need all of them.  I want to know which bundles I should install to get the packages I actually use.

Comment: I think you are using TeX Live packages from a Linux distro rather than TeX Live from upstream? If so, which things are in which packages is determined by your distro's packagers and will vary from one Linux distro to another. The packaging does not correspond to divisions in upstream's TeX Live.

Comment: that is true, I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: thanks @cfr, that bit of knowledge made my search way easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @cfr in a comment the packages are bundled by the distributer rather than the TeX Live base.  In this case I needed to be looking for MacPorts specific bundles:

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages